# Python: Function and Argument list.... is it possible?

Tags: python, list, function-calls

I am writing some code that receives functions with variable numbers of arguments.  I also have lists of those arguments (but the functions expect separate arguments, not one list).  Is there a way to convert this list into arguments of a form that the functions might like (and sadly, they cannot just be converted to strings)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, just prefix the list with a `*` to unpack it:

```
args = [1, 2, 3]
foo(*args) # equivalent to foo(1, 2, 3)
```

More details available [at the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).